# Append objects to an array fails unit tets

Tags: c#, arrays, unit-testing, xunit

I am new to unit testing.

I have an extension method that appends objects to an array of objects. But it fails unit tests anytime I run it. Below is my extension method

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Appends the given objects to the array source.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The specified type of the array</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">The original array of values</param>
    /// <param name="toAdd">The values to append to the source.</param>
    /// <returns>The concatenated array of the specified type</returns>
    public static T[] Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] toAdd) => source.Concat(toAdd).ToArray();
```

... and here is my test

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("Test", "Local", 3, "First Test")]
    [InlineData("Test", "Removable", 15, "Second Test")]
    [InlineData("Test", "Dedicated", 33, "Third Test")]
    public void AppendToArray_ArrayNotEmpty(string origin, string filePath, int lineNumber, string message)
    {
        object[] args = { };

        args.Append(origin, filePath, lineNumber, message);

        Assert.NotEmpty(args);
    }
```

Is there something I am missing? I am using XUnit as my test framework.

Comment: You create a new Array in your extension method. args won't change. You need to use the returned Array from your extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'Append' method does not modify the `source` argument, so you need to assign the return value to something when you call it. Like so:

```
args = args.Append(origin, filePath, lineNumber, message)
```